# Load a website from my website

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I was wondering if its possible to load a website within a website

So I have my index.html file. And when you go to that file in the center it will have like an iFrame or something that will load http://google.com and you can navigate google within my website

Comment: Yes you can use an iframe if the site allows it to be framed. Google does not.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct on using an iFrame to load another site like YouTube.

```
<div style='width:1000px;margin:auto;'>
    <iframe id="theFrame" src="http://www.youtube.com" style="width:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: @epascarello When I paste this code it's just white. https://evemirror.com/mirror/modules/lyft/

Comment: You can load other sites with iFrames, I was unaware that Google doesn't allow you to load their website. I thought the only restriction was not editing JS if its another domain.

Comment: Is there anyway to get around this for websites that wont let you load it?

Comment: Huh, I just tried it and I guess chrome defaults now to not allowing cross site loading... I haven't used iFrames in years so my answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can load sites in iframes if they allow it.

BUT not all sites allow it since they set headers with [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) which the browser detects and does not allow the site to load. If you try to stick google into an iframe you will get this error message in your console.

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? Maybe without iFrame?

Comment: Write your own browser and ignore the restrictions?